# History replaceState no longer working in Chrome for local file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm using window.history.replaceState() to change the query string of a HTML file that was accessed using file:///C:/...

This used to work in Chrome, Internet Explorer and FireFox, but no longer works in Chrome. Not sure when it stopped working. I have Chrome 45.0.2454.85. It still works in the other 2 browsers.

I am getting:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History':
>   A history state object with URL
>   'file:///C:/Users/Michael/Desktop/test.html?Q=NewQueryString' cannot
>   be created in a document with origin 'null'.

Sorry, but this doesn't work in any hosted fiddle. You can copy the code to a local HTML file to see it for yourself:

```
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="clickme()">Click me</button>
<script>
function clickme() {
    window.history.replaceState({ "html": undefined, "pageTitle": "NewTitle"}, "", "?Q=NewQueryString");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Obviously I could host this on a server but was trying to keep simple. This is a simple scrum board that we are using hosted by Git. It hits a 3rd party web service to get the data. Any ideas on working around the error.

Comment: what version , because for me thats working

Comment: Chrome 45.0.2454.85 not working for me.

Comment: This is messed up. I sketch out all my apps as local HTML files in Chrome. Sad to see this no longer works due to jQuery Mobile requiring `replaceState()`.

Answer (score 4):

It stopped working on Chrome 45.
Here I filled an issue on code.google:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=529313

Setting the --allow-file-access-from-files is a good solution if you do just need to run it on your own computer.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. As a workaround, I started Chrome with --allow-file-access-from-files flag.

But think this is not the best solution.

Below is an example of how I'm running:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --app=file: ///C:/APP/index.html --allow-file-access-from-files

If someone find a better solution, please let us know.

Comment: How do you run it on Windows? Start => Run => "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --app=file:///C:/Users/Test/Desktop/test.html --allow-file-access-from-files gives me not found.

Answer (score 0):

[The Chromium team have marked this as `WontFix`](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=301210#c7), and instead recommend against using `file://` URLs in your application.

You have two options:

#### Option A: Use `hash` instead.

You are still able to use `window.history.replaceState`/`pushState` to modify the `hash` component of `file://` URLs.

To set some hash params:

```
window.history.replaceState(null, "", "#?a=param1&b=param2);
```

To read some hash params:

```
const hashString = window.location.hash;
const queryString = hashString.startsWith("#?") ? hashString.substring(2) : hashString;
const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
```

To clear hash params:

```
// Clear query string
window.history.replaceState(null, "", window.location.pathname + window.location.search);
```

#### Option B: Use `document.location.href` as legacy behaviour

It is possible instead update the `document.location.href` as a hacky solution for those file URLs. This will reload the page, but depending on the application this may still be viable.

When not a `file://` URL you can still continue to use the typical `window.history.replaceState`/`pushState` functionality.

For example:

```
const queryString = "a=param1&b=param2"

// Set query string
if (window.location.protocol === "file:") {
  // If application is opened as a file (not served over HTTP), we cannot use `window.history`.
  const newLocation = `${window.location.protocol}//${window.location.pathname}?${queryString}`;
  if (document.location.href !== newLocation) {
    document.location.href = newLocation;
  }
} else {
  window.history.replaceState(null, "", `/?${queryString}`);
}
```