# Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router

I use webpack (1.12.2), react (0.14.2), react-router (1.0.0-rc4) and [history](https://github.com/rackt/history) (1.13.0) libraries.

When I build project with webpack, in google chrome console I get error:

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'file:///Users/and/devel/Wond/index.html' cannot be created in a document with origin 'null'.
```

In [createBrowserHistory.js](https://github.com/rackt/history/blob/master/modules/createBrowserHistory.js) line 41.

In my source code (index.jsx) I use createBrowserHistory:

```
var createBrowserHistory = require('history/lib/createBrowserHistory');
let history = createBrowserHistory();

ReactDOM.render(<Router routes={routes} history={history} />, document.getElementById('content'));
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32398578/history-replacestate-no-longer-working-in-chrome-for-local-file

Comment: Then I get error: `Warning: Location "/Users/and/devel/Wond_dist/index.html" did not match any routes`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your document has the `origin 'null'` because you are loading it from a file scheme URI.

Install a web server and load your HTML document from there.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate off of Quentin's answer. You can run it on a web server using:

```
npx http-server Wond_dist
```

Where `Wond_dist` is the public or distribution folder.

You can read more about http-server here: https://github.com/http-party/http-server

There are also many more web servers you can run it on in this post: [Using Node.js as a simple web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084360/using-node-js-as-a-simple-web-server)