# Why is the method history.pushState() not working in my local HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

It's my first time here so be easy on me.
I'm currently looking for a way to change the current URL without redirecting the user to a new page. I want to include an `?id=` in the URL. 
I found a bunch of topics here about `history.pushState()` and it actually works for me in the browser. It is working in the JavaScript console while I'm on google.com but as soon as I try it in my local .html file it doesn't work!

So here is the basic example:

```js
function changeURL() {
  var stateObj = {
    info: "new page"
  };
  
  history.pushState(stateObj, "New Page", "newpage.html");
}
```

```html
<button onclick=changeURL()> Test </button>
```

If I type the function into my browser it works, but as soon as I open my .html file it won't work. It doesn't do anything.

If I open my html and type the code into the JS Console that's what I get :

```
VM58:2 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': A history state object with URL'file:///C:/Users/conta/Desktop/test/newpage.html' cannot be created in a document with origin 'null' and URL 'file:///C:/Users/conta/Desktop/test/Test.html'.
at <anonymous>:2:13
```

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Is that button inside of a form element?

Comment: No I just created a blank html file. Its the only code in the .html and in the .js files.

It doesn't even change the URL if I put the history.pushState() outside the function. I saw that in a video that I will just change the url but even that will not work for me.

Comment: Error shows that you run the html page directly on the browser, instead of running it on web server (e.g localhost). You should use a local server to test `pushState`, as i dont think it is possible to call it from `file:///`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [History replaceState no longer working in Chrome for local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32398578/history-replacestate-no-longer-working-in-chrome-for-local-file)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use

```
document.location.href = 'newPageUrl';
```

That is the usual way rather that hacking into the history.

Comment: There's an example of how this might look in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77093671/3213602